# Whats the easiest way to make a dynamic line graph from a mysql database?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, graph

So what I'm doing is storing data from a website every 4hrs. I want to have a line graph of the last two days, the y-axis would be number of players and that value can be anywhere from 0-30,000, the value is dependent on the scrape of the website.

What is the best way to store the data in mysql and where is a easy to use graphing solution?

Has anyone used [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a table structure like

```
Player_Stats
players int
hour int
```

Then each hour you could write something like:

`insert into Player_stats (players, hour) values(NUMBEROFPLAYERS, HOUR#)`;

Where HOUR# is a value from 1 to X number of possible hours (if you want to only store things in a running log, otherwise, change hour to a timestamp)....the insert would be more like

```
insert into Player_Stats (players, timestamp) values(NUMBEROFPLAYERS, NOW());
```

Then you'd  retreive your data with:

`select players, hour from Player_Stats`;

Or if you kept things in perpetuity and wanted to grab a range from now to 2 days ago:

```
select players, timestamp from Player_Stats where timestamp between now() and date_sub(timestamp, interval 2 day);
```

Then you could use  a charting library like Google Visualizations...they have good documentation on formatting the data specifically for their different charts.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) is exactly what you're looking for. It can create any type of chart from a data set, and is very customizable.

As for the actual data retrieving, the answers above will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar. I stored the number of players along with a time stamp in a table, then used jquery and [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a cron to run a `SELECT TO OUTFILE myFile` statement regularly. Note that `myFile` cannot be an existing file for security purposes ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)), so you'd have to have the cron also delete the file after the plot is created.

I have found [ploticus](http://ploticus.sourceforge.net/doc/welcome.html) to be very easy to work with, and can make some very complex plots without too much difficulty.